# module to appear below category blog

Tags: module-display, category-blog

In my Joomla installation, I need to display one module (call it myModule) at the bottom of a category blog, in the same position (say user3). myModule is a custom html module. The category blog is assigned to a menu and it is coming properly.

When I assign myModule to the same menu, myModule appears on the screen at the top of user3 position. How do I go about to make it appear below the category blog? I tried with module ordering, but doesn't work. If I assign two modules for the same menu, then the modules appear as per the ordering. How do I control the ordering between a module and a menu assignment?

Answer (score 3):

The category blog is part of the component area in your template, but the 
module position is different than the component area, by default you can't
load a module inside component area (blog layout) in the same position.

One simple solution is check your template positions and add your module
below the component area.

Go to **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Templates**, from here change the
 value
in the option **Preview Module Positions**, check your positions in:
**yoursite.com?tp=1**

From the option **Menu Assignment** you can't control the order.

Regards.